# Concatenation in Python in Wrong order and Overwrites part of String

Tags: python, loops, concatenation, paramiko, overwrite

I am getting a weird output from a Python script

When running the code in a loop for the actual execution involving Paramiko it seems to reverse order of the variable to print, while overwriting the beguinning of the output..

All source text to process is the same for both. One is grabbed via Paramiko over ssh from router, another I manually grabbed and pasted it as a local variable.

**Current output:**

```
with testis 10.8.11.72 from 10.8.11.72 (10.111.72.1)
```

**Desired Ouput and Output with Static local variable:**

```
Best Path is 10.8.11.73 from 10.8.11.73 (10.111.73.1) with localpref 120
```

I have no earthly Idea why this is going on. Please see below for more info and execution. **Help?**

**Code:**

```
import paramiko

router_channel.send('sh ip bgp 10.23.24.32\n')
buff = ''
best_test =()
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = router_channel.recv(99999)
    buff += resp
#DMVPN variable Declaration.
bgp_show = buff
bgp_list =  bgp_show.split('Local')
bgp_list.pop(0)
for x in bgp_list:
    if 'best' in x:
        best_list = x.split('\n')
        for x in best_list:
            best_list = [x.strip(' ') for x in best_list]
            local_pref = best_list[2]
            local_pref = local_pref.split(',')
            local_pref = local_pref[2]
            best_test = best_list[1]
        print '********'
        print buff
        print '********'
        print "Best Path is " + best_test + " with " + "test"
        print '********'
```

**Execution of the code:**

```
dirp@localhost Test Python Scripts]$ python splice.py
    ********
    sh ip bgp 10.23.24.32
    BGP routing table entry for 10.23.24.32/28, version 367886
    Paths: (6 available, best #5, table default)
      Advertised to update-groups:
     1          2          3          4          5          6          7         
     9         
  Refresh Epoch 1
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.111.73 from 10.8.111.73 (10.111.73.2)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 105, valid, internal
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
  Refresh Epoch 2
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.11.72 from 10.8.11.72 (10.111.72.1)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 120, valid, internal, best
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0x0
  Refresh Epoch 3
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.11.73 from 10.8.11.73 (10.111.73.1)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 110, valid, internal
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
router#
********
 With testis 10.8.11.72 from 10.8.11.72 (10.111.72.1)
********
```

**Static Code:**

```
bgp_list =  bgp.split('Local')
bgp_list.pop(0)

#pprint.pprint( bgp_list )

#print bgp_list[2]

for x in bgp_list:
    if 'best' in x:
        best_list = x.split('\n')
        for x in best_list:
            best_list = [x.strip(' ') for x in best_list]
            local_pref = best_list[2]
            local_pref = local_pref.split(',')
            local_pref = local_pref[2]
        print '********'
        print bgp
        print '********'
        print "Best Path is " + best_list[1] + ' with' + local_pref
        print '********'
```

**Ouput when not putting it in a loop but assigning the variable locally:**

```
derp@localhost Test Python Scripts]$ python splitty1.py 
********
sh ip bgp 10.23.24.32 | exclude local
BGP routing table entry for 10.23.24.32/28, version 122378
  Advertised to update-groups:
     1          2          3          4          5          6          7         
     9         
  Refresh Epoch 1
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.111.72 from 10.8.111.72 (10.111.72.2)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 105, valid, internal
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
  Refresh Epoch 1
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.11.72 from 10.8.11.72 (10.111.72.1)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 110, valid, internal
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
  Refresh Epoch 2
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.11.73 from 10.8.11.73 (10.111.73.1)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 120, valid, internal, best
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0x0
  Refresh Epoch 2
  Local
    10.8.11.73 from 10.9.0.1 (10.15.1.41)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 120, valid, internal
      Originator: 10.111.73.1, Cluster list: 10.15.1.41
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
  Refresh Epoch 2
  Local
    10.8.11.73 from 10.8.0.1 (10.15.1.41)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 120, valid, internal
      Originator: 10.111.73.1, Cluster list: 10.15.1.41
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
  Refresh Epoch 2
  Local, (Received from a RR-client)
    10.8.111.73 from 10.8.111.73 (10.111.73.2)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 115, valid, internal
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0
********
Best Path is 10.8.11.73 from 10.8.11.73 (10.111.73.1) with localpref 120
********
[derp@localhost Test Python Scripts]$
```

Comment: Your output dump shows `With testis` (but preceded by a space), your summary at the top shows `with testis` (lowercase, and no space). Which one is it? It's hard to imagine how Python could either capitalize the `w` when there are no capital `W`s in your code, or how it could magicallly remove the space before the word, so neither output seems very likely…

Comment: fixed as it was a formatting error on my part when trying to keep the two scripts one in the same up to the points that matter.

Comment: What did you fix? I don't see any edit history. And the "Current output" and "Execution of the Code" sections are still showing different things, neither of which matches what your posted code could possibly print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`router_channel.recv` is returning Windows-format text, where each line ends in `'\r\n'`. But you create a list with `x.split('\n')`. That means every line (except possibly the last) will end with `'\r'`.

On a non-Windows system, if you print out a `'\r'`, that moves the cursor back to column 1 without advancing the line. So, when you do this:

```
print "Best Path is " + best_test + " with " + "test"
```

You're printing:

```
Best Path is blah blah blah\r with test
```

Which will come out as:

```
 with testis blah blah blah
```

---

The simplest solution is to use the [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method instead of `str.split('\n')`. That automatically takes Windows line endings into account:

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries. This method uses the [*universal newlines*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) approach to splitting lines…

And if you follow the link, it explains universal newlines:

> A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`, the Windows convention `'\r\n'`, and the old Macintosh convention `'\r'`…

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Worked like a charm. Changed `best_list = x.split('\n')` to `best_list = x.splitlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

These lines make me uneasy --

```
for x in best_list:
        best_list = [x.strip(' ') for x in best_list]
```

You're apparently modifying the value of best_list inside a loop through the values in best_list. Even if you think you know what that does, I don't.

Try using a different variable name for the "inner" best_list and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I tried this by using `for x in best_list: best_items = [x.strip(' ') for x in best_list]` And no change in output occured.